# What is the smallest value of the incident angle in Bragg's law?

Tags: reflection, refraction, interference, diffraction, braggs-law

The title of my question basically is what I want to know. In Bragg's law, $nλ = 2 d \sin{\theta}$, if we want to find, let's say, $d$, and know only $\lambda$ and $n$, but not $\theta$, what could be the possible values of $d$? Does it depend on $n$? Because if we were to calculate the limits of $d$, then the smallest $d$ value would be when $\theta = 90^{\circ}$, but, if $\theta=0^{\circ}$, then we get a division from 0. So my guess is that it depends on the value of $n$ in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\theta$ has to be bigger than $0$ for Bragg's law to be meaningful. You can see this algebraically, since Bragg's law becomes $1=0$ for $\theta=0$ and $d, n, \lambda > 0$. The fact that you need $\theta>0$ to get Bragg scattering should also be clear if you look at a picture of the geometry, such as this one from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bragg%27s_law)

[image]

If you know $n$ and $\lambda$, but not $d$ and $\theta$ (except for knowing that $\theta>0$), then all you can calculate is the combination $d\sin\theta$. You can't distinguish $d$ and $\theta$ with the given information. However, you generally will know $\theta$, since that will be determined by the angle at which you (as an experimenter) are sending light at the surface of a crystal.

Answer (score 0):

Bragg's law tells you at what angle *θ* you can see a diffraction line (corresponding to  an interplanar spacing *d*) in a diffraction pattern. The lowest order of reflection *n*=1 falls at lower angle (for example the reflection 100), then you can have higher order of reflections at higher angles (for example the reflections 200, 300, ...).

The lower the scattering angle, the larger the interplanar spacing. If you don't know *θ*, you cannot know *d*. On the other hand, *θ* depends on the wavelenght *λ* and hence the same interplanar spacing *d* will originate peaks at different *θ* using different wavelenghts *λ*. This is because the interplanar spacing *d* is an intrinsic and fixed property of the material, whereas *λ* depends on the instrumental set-up.

Comment: Oh, so maybe there is a formula for the relation of the wavelength and the angle theta?

Comment: You wrote above this formula, is the Bragg's law. You will observe a diffraction peak everytime λ=2dsinθ, otherwise you will have only background. In your experiment you know λ (the anti-cathod of your diffractometer), you measure θ in the diffraction pattern and so you can calculate the different interplanar spacings d characterising the crystal structure of your sample. The different interplanar spacings d will give peaks at different angles θ.